# Disambiguation of [loki] in favor of [grafana-loki]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag description of the  [loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loki) tag reads:

> Loki is a C++ library of designs, containing flexible implementations of common design patterns and idioms.
>
> ---
>
> Loki was written by Andrei Alexandrescu. It provides many features used in so-called modern C++, such as metaprogramming facilities, smart pointers, but also implementations of common idioms like pimpl or factories.

The last use of this tag with the meaning as described above was on Feb 22, 2022. And for the last eight years, only four questions were tagged with [loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loki) with clear relation to the mentioned description.

On the other hand, this tag is widely used as a de facto synonym for [grafana-loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grafana-loki).

Of the 175 questions tagged with [loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loki), only 36 are simultaneously tagged with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). And there is only a [handful of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loki%20-c%2B%2B%20-grafana%20-grafana-loki%20-promtail%20-logql%20-logging?tab=newest&page=1&pagesize=15) neither tagged with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) nor something related to Grafana of logging.

I suggest:

1. Create a separate tag [c++-loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-loki) with info from the current tag [loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loki),
2. Retag questions that are related to the mentioned library with the newly created tag,
3. Make [loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loki) a synonym for [grafana-loki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grafana-loki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags have been merged, the suggested synonym is created, and the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34798019) and [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34798020) have been copied over to the new tag.

A search for `[loki] -[grafana] -[grafana-loki]` returned 22 questions, all of which appeared to be Grafana-related.

```
updating post history, 153 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 143 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 73 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'loki': [loki] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 499
tag remapping of [grafana-loki] and [loki] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
80 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
5 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym loki -> grafana-loki was approved!
```